# Xcode5 - Openssl building issue

Tags: ios7, openssl, xcode5, ios7.1, libcrypto

Try to build openssl in xcode5  shows  "libcrypto.a" and libssl.a" files missing error. i am using the latest openssl files from Github. i can't find the exact problem, if anybody have any idea please free to share.

Thanks

Comment: You might provide the link to Github, and mention the iOS target and build versions. Some of the OpenSSL versions on Github are quite old and may not be compatible with Xcode 5/iOS 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just update xcode5.0 to xcode 5.1 .it will work ....

Answer (score 0):

> Try to build openssl in xcode5 shows "libcrypto.a" and libssl.a" files missing error.

There's an example of setting include and library paths using Xcode at [User Guide for the OpenSSL FIPS Object Module v2.0](https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf), Appendix E-2. On page 130, it shows you how to set the paths for OpenSSL under iOS (`ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS`, `USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`, `OTHER_LDFLAGS`, etc). Setting paths applies to native and cross-compiled - there's no difference. You can also ignore that its written for the FIPS module - again, there's no difference.

If you have more information, then add it to your question. Otherwise, the folks on Stack Overflow will be taking stabs in the dark.